# react-spring/parallex formatting bad

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-spring

Using react-spring/parallax, as soon as I add the <Parallax> element, the webpage becomes horizontally scrollable, adds a vertical scrollbar and formatting goes haywire.

I was expecting for it to center align and not add a horizontal scrollbar and extra vertical scrollbar, I tried changing the width of all the elements and nothing works except deleting the <Parallax> element

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Parallax, ParallaxLayer } from "@react-spring/parallax";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parallax pages={2}>
        <ParallaxLayer offset={0}>
          <h1>TEST1</h1>
        </ParallaxLayer>
        <ParallaxLayer offset={1}>
          <h1>TEST2</h1>
        </ParallaxLayer>
      </Parallax>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGQTa.png)

Comment: Man I have this exact same issue. Sad to see there are no responses. I will update if I find anything, but I may need to use a different library :/ Here from fireships video